# iOS - is it possible to get a history of user locale/timezones programmatically for HealthKit apps?

Tags: timezone, location, ios14, healthkit

I have an app that is reading data from HealthKit and is calculating sleep statistics for the user going 3 years back. One data point I can offer to the user is the sunrise/sunset times for the current location.

However, if the user has travelled over the last 3 years, then sunrise/sunset calculation needs to be performed on that coordinate, not the present location.

**How can I obtain history of time zone or coordinates for the user? (rough 100-500km accuracy) Is this information recored anywhere in HealthKit?**

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the samples have metadata value for the key [HKMetadataKeyTimeZone](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkmetadatakeytimezone)